# Ubuntu 18.04 Monitor not recognized

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have a pc with Ubuntu 18.04 with three monitors connected. Two monitors connected with VGA and HDMI to my graphics card (GeForce GT710) and one monitor connected directly to the motherboard (Asus H81M-K).

During boot, all three monitors show image but once ubuntu finishes booting only the monitors connected to the graphics card are recognized. I tried enabling the onboard graphics card in the bios and it still doesn't work.

This is the `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+
    1680x1050     59.95
    1600x900      60.00
    1440x900      59.89
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02
    1280x800      59.81
    1280x720      60.00
    1152x864      75.00
    1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
    800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
    640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97   59.94    50.00
    1680x1050     59.95
    1600x900      60.00
    1440x900      59.89
    1400x1050     59.98
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02
    1280x800      59.81
    1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
    1152x864      75.00
    1024x768      75.03    60.00
    800x600       75.00    60.32
    720x576       50.00
    720x480       59.94
    640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get my third monitor to be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a driver issue. You will need to use the open source drivers because only one driver can be loaded at a time. It seems you are using the NVIDIA drivers which disable your Intel integrate GPU.